# Running trac on a debian server - error writing to trac.ini

Tags: linux, debian, chmod, trac, chgrp

I have trac running on my debian server and I set it up using mod_wsgi through apache. Now I have everything setup nicely, except I can never seem to write to a projects `trac.ini` file through the site.

I have set the ini file to be writable:

```
sudo chmod +x trac.ini
```

And I have also made it belong to `www-data`:

```
ls -l
-rwxrwxrwx 1 www-data admin 5744 Aug  2 00:00 trac.ini
```

On a similar server I setup a while ago the same call gives me this:

```
ls -l
-rwxrwxrwx 1 www-data www 5904 Mar  20 11:00 trac.ini
```

I am clearly missing something basic here but cannot get it to work!

Comment: You don't say what the permissions are on the directory that trac.ini is in.

Comment: Ah. That might be it. I will try it now...

Comment: Answer that as a question and I will accept. Feel so silly now now checking the dir!